# Get the coordinates from the example of google maps API places search box?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get the coordinates from the search box of the example in google maps API places search box and I can't seem to determine where I can get the coordinates and set them in a variable.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places- 
searchbox
```

Here is the example in google maps API. I already tried calling `bounds` variable and `place.geometry.location` as well but still, I can't get the coordinates of the searched location.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and 
retrieve
    // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
             url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

       if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of the "searched location" are: `place.geometry.location`, which is a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#LatLng).  That object has `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods that return the latitude and longitude of the location and a `toUrlValue()` method that returns a comma delimited string containing both.

so inside the `places.forEach(function(place)`, this code:

```
console.log("marker "+markers.length+" name="+place.name+" coordinates="+place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)+", latitude="+place.geometry.location.lat()+", longitude="+place.geometry.location.lng());
```

will give you the following if you select "Hyde Park, Elizabeth St, Sydney NSW, Australia":

> marker 1 name=Hyde Park coordinates=-33.873138,151.211276, latitude=-33.8731383, longitude=151.2112757

```
places.forEach(function(place) {
  if (!place.geometry) {
    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }
  var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  }));
  console.log("marker "+markers.length+" name="+place.name+" coordinates="+place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)+", latitude="+place.geometry.location.lat()+", longitude="+place.geometry.location.lng());
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/grk7bu8L/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      // log the coordinates of each "place"
      console.log("marker " + markers.length + " name=" + place.name + " coordinates=" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + ", latitude=" + place.geometry.location.lat() + ", longitude=" + place.geometry.location.lng());
      // put the coordinates of each place in the div with id="output"
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "marker " + markers.length + " name=" + place.name + " coordinates=" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>latitude=" + place.geometry.location.lat() + ", longitude=" + place.geometry.location.lng();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: is it also possible to get the coordinates when you drag the marker? i was planning to enable the draggable feature of markers and get the coordinates from that marker when you searched the place, then you drag the marker to precisely choose the place

Comment: [Draggable pin not updating coordinates in Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198844/draggable-pin-not-updating-coordinates-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: will it be possible for me to initially mark my current location, then, you can search for another location and moves the marker to that location?

Comment: Sure.  Search for a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Here is one possible duplicate: [How to move marker to AutoComplete API predicted address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685910/how-to-move-marker-to-autocomplete-api-predicted-address)